# What's the difference from manually config NewRelic on Heroku than using the addon?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, newrelic

I already have an application deployed on Heroku using NewRelic for monitoring.
I did download the config file and my app are being monotired by NewRelic.

Recently I've discovered that exists an add-on on Heroku for use with NewRelic.

What could be the benefits of using that add-on instead of using the manual configuration that I've already made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only benefit is a single billing solution and Single Sign On(SSO) Features. Outside of that, the manual configuration in which you have done allows you to monitor multiple apps on a single New Relic dashboard.

Comment: So in my case, as I already have a New Relic accound I will still using the manual configuration. Thank you by the help.

Comment: Also it's worth noting that you get a much higher version of New Relic for FREE by using the addon compared to do if you are using the free tier direct from New Relic.